# Export a function as default while destructuring it for uses within the same class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm working with the React Context API, and I've got the following as an example

```js
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';

const FooContext = createContext({
  bar: false,
  toggleBar: () => {}
});

export const FooContextConsumer = FooContext.Consumer;

export const FooContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [bar, setBar] = useState(false);

  const toggleBar = () => setBar(!bar);

  return (
    <FooContext.Provider value={{ bar, toggleBar }}>
      {children}
    </FooContext.Provider>
  )
};

export default FooContext;
```

Now, there's a lot of exports going on here. I know that the `createContext` functions has `{ Provider, Consumer }` destructure properties available. Is there a way I can use that to compact this code? I've got something like this in mind but that isn't valid syntax unfortunately..

```js
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';

export default ({ Provider, Consumer }) = createContext({
  bar: false,
  toggleBar: () => {}
});

export const FooContextConsumer = Consumer;

export const FooContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [bar, setBar] = useState(false);

  const toggleBar = () => setBar(!bar);

  return (
    <Provider value={{ bar, toggleBar }}>
      {children}
    </Provider>
  )
};
```

So, I want to export `createContext` function as the default, while using the `Provider` and `Consumer` properties of that function within the same file. Is this possible?

*Of course I can do it with a `const` and an `export default` but I was wondering if this is possible as a one-liner.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to name your context in order to further use it in the file:

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';

const Context = createContext({
  bar: false,
  toggleBar: () => {}
});

export const FooContextConsumer = Context.Consumer;

export const FooContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [bar, setBar] = useState(false);

  const toggleBar = () => setBar(!bar);

  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{ bar, toggleBar }}>
      {children}
    </Context.Provider>
  )
};

export default Context;
```

The implementation I'd recommend for consuming the context:

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';

// ...

export const useFooContext = () => useContext(Context);

// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I would stick to your first example. It's clear which `Context` the `Consumer`, and `Provider` belong to.